# Add a sound to all the buttons in a project

Tags: godot, sound

Is there an option on the texture_button or something like that where you can specify a sound to be played on button-press. I have created a global sound_manager but for the button presses, I have to manually code it everywhere the script has a button_pressed signal. Or some kind of logic that when a button is pressed anywhere in the project, sound_manager plays a particular sound.

Comment: Consider extending from TextureButton and allowing audio stream assignment as parameter. [Here's an idea on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/a80gut/i_want_to_make_a_singleton_sound_manager_is_that/). Disclaimer - I have very little experience with Godot, so just giving you an idea.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using an [AutoLoad](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) script that connects to the "pressed" signal of all buttons in the tree.

Create a `UISoundPlayer` scene which consists of a node with an `AudioStreamPlayer` attached, which is used to play the UI sounds.

Add that scene as an AutoLoad, and attach this script to the root node:

```
extends Node

func _ready():
    # when _ready is called, there might already be nodes in the tree, so connect all existing buttons
    connect_buttons(get_tree().root)
    get_tree().connect("node_added", self, "_on_SceneTree_node_added")

func _on_SceneTree_node_added(node):
    if node is Button:
        connect_to_button(node)

func _on_Button_pressed():
    $ButtonSound.play()

# recursively connect all buttons
func connect_buttons(root):
    for child in root.get_children():
        if child is BaseButton:
            connect_to_button(child)
        connect_buttons(child)

func connect_to_button(button):
    button.connect("pressed", self, "_on_Button_pressed")
```

The code should be self-explanatory. It connects to all buttons on _ready and to newly added buttons.

Here is an example project: https://gofile.io/d/LTBvQf

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be to make a new Scene, add an empty button to it, add a script to it and connect the pressed signal to sound_manager inside the init function. Then use this scene for every button which should make a sound. And, if the, sound is made an export var it can be customized in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Jummit's answer above (which got me out a bind because I didn't plan ahead, assuming Buttons would have a built-in way to make a noise, thank you Jummit)...

Be sure to set your `UISoundPlayer` node to `Pause Mode Process` so that the sounds still play when the game is paused.